# Self-comparisons with a $where query

Tags: mongodb

As part of an upgrade script, I want to use `$where` to find docs where the id matches one of the fields. I know that's slow because it's done with a cursor, but that's OK with me; I'm only going to run it once. But I can't get it to work:

```
> db.things.drop()
true

> stuff = {}
{ }

> db.things.save(stuff)

> stuff.original_id = stuff._id
ObjectId("4ff5f9f97fadec5abb7b5392")

> db.things.save(stuff)

//why doesn't this return anything?
> db.things.find({$where: "this._id == this.original_id"})

//interstingly, this works fine
> db.things.find({$where: "this._id == this._id"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ff5f9f97fadec5abb7b5392"), "original_id" : ObjectId("4ff5f9f97fadec5abb7b5392") }
```

What's wrong here? Why can't I compare `_id` to `original_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectId` is an object. The `==` operator here tests for reference equality.

```
> ObjectId("4ff5fbed3a015a91f85e80bb") == ObjectId("4ff5fbed3a015a91f85e80bb")
false
```

But if operands are simpler types (numbers or strings) it checks for value equality.

```
> '4ff5fbed3a015a91f85e80bb' == '4ff5fbed3a015a91f85e80bb'
true
```

So, this simple workaround will work:

```
> db.where.find({$where: "this._id.toString() == this.orig_id.toString()"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ff5fbed3a015a91f85e80bb"), "orig_id" : ObjectId("4ff5fbed3a015a91f85e80bb") }
```

Here's [a post with much more info on comparison operators in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/125816).

And here's [another article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/).

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of that. See the rules in the === section here: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/